# Let $f$ be a closed path in $S^1$ at $1$. Show that if $f$ is not surejctive, then $\deg(f)=0$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let $f$ be a closed path in $S^1$ at $1$. Show that if $f$ is not surejctive, then $\deg(f)=0$.

Intuitively I think I understand why this is the case. Since $f$ isn't surjective the image doesn't contain all the points of the sphere and thus $f$ cannot wind around the sphere any number of times. However I don't know how to prove this formally. Wikipedia doesn't give me any nice definition for the degree of a map except for the case when the map is $S^n \to S^n$, where the dimensions agree. Then the degree is defined to be the coefficient of the induced map $f_\ast : H_n(S^n) \to H_n(S^n)$, but here the dimensions don't agree. So would I be looking at $$f_\ast:H_1([0,1]) \to H_1(S^1)?$$

The first space should be contractible and $H_1(S^1) \cong \Bbb Z$ so I think $f_\ast$ should be the zero map which would imply that $\deg(f)= 0 $ right?

Comment: A mapping $f : [0,1] \to X$ with $f(0) = f(1)$ is essentially the same thing as a mapping $f: S^1 \to X$. Do you see why? This is the sense in which $f$ has a degree.

Comment: What is the source of your question?

Answer (score 0):

Remark that removing a point from a the circle result in a space  homeomorphic to a line which is contractible.
Generally, a punctured sphere is homeomorphic to euclidean space which is contractible. The crucial point is that the degree of a map is homotopy invariant.